# How to search a string element in a class arraylist? (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

My question is that there is a method printPetInfoByName() searches the list of pets for every pet of a given name, and prints the pet’s information, using the toString() method.
The arraylist is of type Pet and name is given from main method (i haven't coded it yet)
I need to print info of a pet using toString() by searching arraylist. If the given name is present in list then it will print info.

my code looks like this[image]

but it produces error > incompatible types: Pet cannot be converted to CharSequence for line 20
if i write for(String search:list)
then it gives error that Pet cannot be converted to String for line 18

Comment: `contains` doesn't know what to do with a `Pet`. You probably need to change it to something like it's name, making the line `if(name.contains(search.getName()))`.

Comment: @Clashsoft if i write it that way then it states "cannot find symbol" for getName()

Comment: @Masu That's because you need to add the `getName` method in the `Pet` class to return the name of the `Pet`.

Comment: Please put your actual code in the question rather than a picture.

Comment: @ChetanKinger there is a getName() in Pet class but Pet class is not required to be inherited in AnimalHospital class

Comment: ok it got compiled after using getName(). Thanks
but it prints hexadecimal address not the info when i input data
there has to be a problem with toString method. but i dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for your method:

```
public void printPetInfoByName(String name) {
    for (Pet search : list)
        if (search.getName().contains(name))
            search.toString(); //System.out.println(search.toString());
}
```

Define toString method in abstract class **Pet**.

Answer (score 0):

`String.contains` checks if a substring is present in the string. It takes a CharSequence as parameter, and you are now giving it a Pet. That why you get the error.

I assume you have some kind of name field on your pets that you can access with a get method? Instead of checking whether or not the string contains the pet, consider asking if the pet's name is equal to the search string.

I think you should get your way working first. But if you are interested java 8 streams are a good tool when working with Collections. Here is how one could solve your problem using them:

```
list.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

`list.stream()` "starts" the stream.

`filter` filters all elements p where p's name is equal to the name you pass as an argument.

`forEach` does something for all elements in the stream. Note that by filtering it, the remaining elements are those we want.

Answer (score 0):

a String cant not compare with the complex object.They are not the same type,so your program doesn't know how to work with it .